# C++ cross compiling on Ubuntu for Windows linking LIBEAY DLL's 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, dll, cross-compiling

I have an Ubuntu set-up which is perfectly cross compiling for Windows except for one point. When I cross compile a 64-bit Windows executable, it compiles perfectly. However when I try to start the executable it returns me an error that it can't start correctly. Error code: `0xc000007b`

I have done some research and it seems that the 64-bit executable tries to use the `LIBEAY32.dll` file. How can I specify the `LIBEAYxx.dll` file during compilation so the 64-bit executable will use the `LIBEAY64.dll` instead of the `LIBEAY32.dll`?

Comment: Rather than trying to get cross compiling working reliably, I'd suggest the path of least resistance would be to simply set up a Windows virtual machine and build the code natively there. That would - as a bonus - also give you an environment where you can debug Windows related  issues.

Comment: Thanks, however cross-compiling is way easier than compiling on Windows at all. Thanks